# Change text in %%GLOBAL_YouSave%%

Tags: bigcommerce

As I am new to Big commerce, so not getting how to change the global variable text.

Currently the global variable %%GLOBAL_YouSave%% display text as "You Save ", but we want to display the text "You are saving  on RRP"

Could anybody please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is a global or is it an LNG value? You should just delete the global value and replace with the string you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is Global variable instead of LNG value.
Its is displaying like (You save £2.09) but i want this to display (You are saving £2.09 on RRP)

Comment: Globals are generated from the core app and can't be changed. You could append a string that says "on RRP" so the phrase is You save £2.09 on RRP, but I don't know that you can get "You are saving £2.09 on RRP" without replacing the whole string with a javascript function.